# Azure AD registered app not showing ToS/Privacy links on Consent screen

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to include Terms of Service and/or Privacy Statement links to Azure AD web application consent screen according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-terms-of-service-privacy-statement).

I can see and test the consent screen just fine when appending `&prompt=consent` on login URL `https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.azurewebsites.net%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&client_id=CLIENT_ID&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=NONCE&state=redir%3D%252F&sso_reload=true&prompt=consent` but for some reason ToS/PS links are not shown where they should be (please see documentation link above).

[image: No links shown]

Here's how I have defined them on app manifest:

[image: App manifest with informationalUrls]

Is there something else in addition to defining the URLs that is required for the links to be shown on consent screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue. After changing the application to **multi-tenant**. It works.

[image]

This is my test result.

[image]

Then I check the document again.

> The terms of service and privacy statement are especially critical for
>   user-facing multi-tenant apps--apps that are used by multiple
>   directories or are available to any Microsoft account.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick, too bad documentation is outdated.